# How to make my Scroll View work while it has an Expandable List View in it?

Tags: android, scrollview, expandablelistview

```
        I am having Expandable List View inside a scroll view.Here is my layout :

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

          <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/first_layout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                        <com.tfe.view.GabrielGridView
                            android:id="@+id/sample_grid"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                            android:columnWidth="20dp"
                            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                            android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

                        </com.tfe.view.GabrielGridView>

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout

                        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/first_layout"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >


                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="24dp" />

                        </RelativeLayout>




                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/third_Layout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@id/second_Layout" >

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/divider"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="3dp"/>

                        <ExpandableListView
                            android:id="@+id/expandableListViewLayout"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    Here I am using a **custom GridView** called Gabriel GridView. **My scroll view doesn't work because of my List View inside it. How can I make it work?**
```

Comment: You shouldn't be adding `ListView` to another `ScrollView`. You should look for any other approach to work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good choice to use scrollable view inside another scrollable view. But, if you want to make this regardless warnings of using nested scrollable views. Then create your own custom **NonScrollableExpandableListView** and a wrapper over your custom gridview,**NonScrollableGabrielGridView**. Then override the `onMeasure()` method on both components to be like:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
```

**Again, It's a bad choice**